# JS jquery выбор нужного элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".suggestions-list").on("click", "li", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".input-container").find(".input-text").val($(this).text());

  //ПРОБЛЕМА
  $("div.title-new").find(".input-container").closest(".input-text").val($(this).text());
  //ПРОБЛЕМА
  $(this).closest(".suggestions-list").hide();
});
```

нужно вставить text в input-text который в блоке title-new, никак не получается сделать это через closest, если сделать find то вставит на все поля input-text на странице, что я делаю не так?

вот кусок html для которого это все делается:

```
<div class="title-drom">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-text title-suggestion" type="text" value="значение">
    <ul class="suggestions-list">
    </ul>

    <div class="input-info">
      <span class="is">0</span>
      /
      <span class="max">71</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="title-new">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-text insert-titlenew" type="text" value="значение">
    <div class="input-info">
      <span class="is">0</span>
      /
      <span class="max">50</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest` ищет вверх по цепочке родителей. Он здесь не подходит. Вам просто надо выбрать этот инпут внутри известных родителей:

```
$("div.title-new .input-container .input-text").val($(this).text());
```

*Update*

```
$(this).
 closest(".title-drom").
 next(".title-new").
 find(".input-container .input-text").
 val($(this).text());
```

Comment: да так я делал, но это работает немного иначе чем мне нужно, оно вставляет во все найденные поля, которых может быть несколько на странице

Comment: @rst630 где находится элемент с классом "title-new", в чей инпут Вы хотите записать значение?

Answer (score 3):

> что я делаю не так?

Пытаетесь найти у `.input-container` *родителя* с классом `.input-text`, тогда как в разметке последний является *дочерним*.

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь [с описанием метода `closest()` в оф.документации](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

---

Что касается самого кода - такой вариант и работает, и немного логичнее+читаемее (хоть и на 2 строчки больше):

```js
$(".suggestions-list").on("click", "li", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var list = $(this).closest(".suggestions-list"), 
      text = $(this).text(); 
  list.siblings(".input-text").first().val(text);    // присвоение соседнему инпуту
  $("div.title-new .input-text").first().val(text);  // присвоение инпуту в #title-new
  list.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="title-drom">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-text title-suggestion" type="text" value="значение">
    <ul class="suggestions-list">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="title-new">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-text insert-titlenew" type="text" value="значение">
  </div>
</div>
```

*<sub>Вызов `first()` в данном случае не обязателен, конечно - но теоретически, может чуть ускорить выполнение (зависит от реализации jQuery).

И по-моему, писать `first()` в случаях когда нужно выбрать первый элемент коллекции независимо от ее размера, это хорошая привычка.</sub>*

Comment: Отлично! только я просто изменил свою строку на $("div.title-new .input-container .input-text").first().val($(this).text()); добиться изменения во всех полях на странице мне удавалось и раньше, а вот как сделать изменение только соседнего поля рядом с которым происходят манипуляции я не знал. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @rst630, не за что :) Пожалуйста отметьте принятым ответ **Igor**, где предложен выбранный Вами вариант (нажмите на галочку слева от его ответа).

Comment: @yar85 "You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar."

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вы хотите чтоб при клике на элемент из списка его значение вставлялось в input-text блока title-new ?

```js
$(".suggestions-list").on('click', function(e){
$('.title-new .input-text').val(e.target.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="title-drom">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-text title-suggestion" type="text" value="значение">
    <ul class="suggestions-list">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="title-new">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-text insert-titlenew" type="text" value="значение">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да все верно, но суть еще в том что таких блоков на странице может быть несколько, а вставить нужно только в ближайший

Comment: @rst630 каких блоков может быть несколько? блоков со списком? suggesions-list ? Сформулируйте более ясно с несколькими блоками чтоли код предоставьте и куда значения попадать должны. А то догадываться можно да и только